# Is " located on the upper side than..." understandable?

Tags: adverbial-phrases

> It should be located above the line.

For some reasons, I need to rephrase the sentence above using "upper side".  My drafts are as follows:

> 1. It should be located on the upper side than the line.
> 2. It should be located on the upper side relative/with respect to the line.
> 3. It should be located on the upper side of the line.

It may seem that all sound strange to natives. Which is at least grammatically correct?

Comment: To me, no.3 is the most idiomatic if you use "upper side".

Comment: I want to know which is the most understandable.